# VBA: Select all slides of defined sections

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm playing with a progress bar (with basically zero experience with VBA whatsoever). I found the following snippet online:

```js
Sub ProgressBar()
    On Error Resume Next
    With ActivePresentation
    .SectionProperties.SlidesCount(
        For N = 2 To .Slides.Count
        .Slides(N).Shapes("Progress_Bar").Delete
        Set s = .Slides(N).Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 0, .PageSetup.SlideHeight - 10, N * .PageSetup.SlideWidth / .Slides.Count, 10)
        Call s.Fill.Solid
        s.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(128, 128, 128)
        s.Line.Visible = False
        s.Name = "Progress_Bar"
        Next N:
    End With
End Sub
```

Note the part with `For N = 2 To .Slides.Count`. I'd like the progress bar not to reach from the second slide the last one but rather from the second slide to the last slide of the section I called "conclusion". How can I do that?

Thanks!

Edit: My current workaround is a hard coded number of slides that I define as a variable at the beginning of the macro and then use the variable throughout the rest of it.

Comment: Try changing `For N = 2 To .Slides.Count` to `For N = 2 To Selection.Slides.Count`

Comment: There is a powerpoint object called "sliderange" which represents a subset of "slides" collection. Further information find [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff744720.aspx)

Comment: I'd like the script to be automated so that I don't have to make the according selection every time I run it.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful reply! It does not really answer my question though, as it does not explain how I can use the sections and their names in creating such a range.

Comment: @Christian Steinmeyer, as far as I understand you cannot acces via VBA  the slides of a section, only maybe by getting the "ID" or the "index" of the section or "firstslide" property. To find a specific slide you have to scan through the "slides" collection. When you want to scan through a part of the "slides" use "sliderange". Look in the object model for the examples like in the link I gave

Comment: @Christine Ross Thanks for the clarification. I'll go with  Steve's answer for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple of bits that should get you started:

LastSlideOf returns the slide index of the last slide in the named section passed to it:

```
Function LastSlideOf(sSectionName As String) As Long
    Dim x As Long

    With ActivePresentation.SectionProperties
        x = SectionIndexOf(sSectionName)
        LastSlideOf = (.FirstSlide(x) + .SlidesCount(x)) - 1
    End With

End Function

Function SectionIndexOf(sSectionName As String) As Long
    Dim x As Long
    With ActivePresentation.SectionProperties
        For x = 1 To .Count
            If .Name(x) = sSectionName Then
                SectionIndexOf = x
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Function
```