# How to get slide number of first slide in a section?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to number only the slides within a specific section. To do this, I need to generate numbering for each slide. Let **first** be the slide number of the first slide in that section. Then, the formula for the number of each slide in the section is:

> Number = Current slide number - first + 1

I currently have code which gives me the current slide number (the Text is within a shape, no need to worry about that).

```
.Text = "Add. Info" & vbNewLine & _
ActiveWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex
```

The section that I'm looking for is named AddInfo.

How do I get the slide number of the first slide in that section?

Comment: I think you should be able to modify the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43516312/vba-select-all-slides-of-defined-sections) to do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the first slide of a specific section, you may use the following function:

```
' Returns the index of the first slide under the section `sectionName`.
' Returns -1 if the section is not found or doesn't have any slides.
Public Function GetFirstSlideNumber(ByVal sectionName As String) As Long
    With ActivePresentation.SectionProperties
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To .Count
            If .Name(i) = sectionName Then
                GetFirstSlideNumber = .firstSlide(i)
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
    End With

    ' Section not found.
    GetFirstSlideNumber = -1
End Function
```

#### Usage:

```
Debug.Print GetFirstSlideNumber("AddInfo")
```

Comment: Thank you! Very stupid question - how do I use this within a sub? I'm not very sure of where to put the function - completely new to this.

Comment: @TheveshTheva Just add the function to a new/existing module and then in your sub/macro, you can use something like `Dim slideNumber As Long : slideNumber = GetFirstSlideNumber("AddInfo")` Is that what you're asking?

Comment: This works absolutely perfect! Thank you so much - more than I had hoped for. :)